# What is the distribution of a sum of a subset of probabilities, with each probability having the same distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, beta-distribution

Suppose I have $k$ outcomes with probabilities, $p_i$, with $p_1+p_2+\dots+p_k=1$. Each probability has the same distribution. What would the distribution of a sum of probabilities be? For example, what would the distribution of $p_1+p_2$ be? The Irwin-Hall distribution is the distribution for the sum of uniformly distributed random variables. Each $p_i$ will be distributed between 0 and 1, but they won't be uniformly distributed. Does the Irwin-Hall distribution have anything to do with it?

I don't require a fully derived answer, but a kick in the right direction would help.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics, and not academia

Comment: Moment generating functions might be useful although it depends on what the distribution is

Comment: I'm confused. You appear to be asking about the distribution of a sum of probabilities. However, probabilities are not random variables, so the question is not meaningful. If you are considering some random variables taking values between 0 and 1 which happen to sum to 1, then don't use the word probabilities, it is confusing. I think you can handle it as you would the sum of any sum of random variables, namely using convolution. Since there is a constraint on the sum, you could remove one random variable from there, so you would for example be working with $X_1$, $X_2$, $1 - X_1 - X_2$.

Comment: Of course, you would have to know the joint distribution of the $X_i$'s to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

The [Irwin-Hall distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) is the distribution of a random variable defined as the sum of a number of independent random variables, each having a uniform distribution.
It won't be useful here since the probabilities $p_i$ are not uniformly distributed nor independent (they need to sum to one).

The distribution that will suit your needs is the [Dirichlet distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution). It is the multivariate generalization of the [beta distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), and has support $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ with $x_i \in [0, 1]$ for $i=1, \ldots, n$ and $\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i = 1$.

Let $\boldsymbol{X} = (X_1, \ldots, X_n) \sim \mbox{Dir}(\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)$, and suppose that one seeks the distribution of $X_1 + X_2$.
By the [aggregation property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution)
$$
\boldsymbol{Y} = (X_1 + X_2, X_3, \ldots, X_n) \sim
\mbox{Dir}(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \ldots, \alpha_n) .
$$
Since [marginal distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) of Dirichlet distributions are beta distributions, we have
$$
X_1 + X_2 \sim \mbox{Beta}\left(\alpha_1 + \alpha_2, \sum_{i = 3}^n \alpha_i\right)
.$$

Answer (score 1):

Probabilities can be treated as random variables and have distributions of their own -if their exact value is unknown. For example, the Beta Distribution is a distribution suited to model the distribution of a probability, since in its standard formulation it ranges in the [0,1] interval.

Assume therefore that each $p_i$ follows a (common as per question) $Beta (a,b)$ (the Uniform $U(0,1)$ is a special case of the beta distribution). The $p_i$'s must satisfy the constraint

$$\sum_{i=1}^kp_i =1 \Rightarrow E\left[\sum_{i=1}^kp_i\right] =1 \Rightarrow k\frac {a}{a+b}=1$$

which determines the one parameter of the beta distribution as a function of the other and of the magnitude of $k$.

What you need next is, as a comment points out, to determine the joint distribution of the $p_i$'s. Are the $p_i$'s independent random variables?

Think (and I suggest you work further) that

$$\sum_{i=1}^kp_i =1 \Rightarrow \left(\sum_{i=1}^kp_i\right)^2 =1 \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^kp_i^2 + 2\sum_{i\neq j}p_ip_j = 1$$

$$\Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^kE[p_i^2] + 2\sum_{i\neq j}E[p_ip_j] = 1 = k\frac {a}{a+b}$$